# Connecting to Twitter using xAuth on iPhone and/or OAuth on Web?

Tags: iphone, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, xauth

I am building a Web site and iPhone app right now. My site and app requires registration.

I have received xAuth permission from Twitter and was going to use this for the iPhone app so that users can connect their Twitter account.

Once they connect their Twitter account, if they log in to the Web, is it possible to make it so their account is still connected?

On the other hand, I am using OAuth verification on the Web. If someone connects their Twitter account on the Web using OAuth, will they still be connected if logging onto the iPhone app?

So basically, I need to make:

User connects account on iPhone app (xAuth) -> User logs in to Web site and is still connected and can post to Twitter from both

User connects on Web (OAuth) -> User logs in to iPhone app and is still connected and can post to Twitter from both

Answer (score 0):

You can do this --- basically once you do the OAuth based login it generate unique Token, so after this data reading is done using Token.

Once you get Token (it can be in Phone/web) use this details between each other so that both of your application can do the rest of operation for the same user without further login.

Comment: Can I do this with xAuth in the iPhone app, too?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about xAuth but yes you can using OAuth